# Save Selected Option Value in Bootstrap Edit Tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

Im trying to make a content edit table and its working in a 80% my only problem is this: When i select a option from the select input its saving the text of all the option from that select, i need to save just the text from the selected option. Any idea?

This is my code

**Function for load data**

```
function load_data()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>planificacion/load_mecanizado",
      dataType:"JSON",
      success:function(data){
        $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>planificacion/load_usuarios",
      dataType:"JSON",
      success:function(data){
        $.each(data,function(key, usuario) {
        $(".seleccionarusuario").append('<option value='+usuario.user_id+'>'+usuario.user_email+'</option>');
      });    
          }
    });
        var html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td id="id_perfil" placeholder="" disabled></td>';
        html += '<td id="string" contenteditable placeholder="ID"></td>';
        html += '<td id="RspCtrPrd" contenteditable placeholder="RspCtrPrd"></td>';
        html += '<td id="ReferenciaP" contenteditable placeholder="Referencia"></td>';
        html += '<td id="cuenta_asociada" contenteditable placeholder="Cuenta Asociada"></td>';

        html += '<td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Agregar</button></td></tr>';
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)

        {
          html += '<tr>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id_perfil+'" data-column_name="id_perfil" disabled>'+data[count].id_perfil+'</td>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id_perfil+'" data-column_name="string" contenteditable>'+data[count].string+'</td>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id_perfil+'" data-column_name="RspCtrPrd" contenteditable>'+data[count].RspCtrPrd+'</td>';
          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id_perfil+'" data-column_name="ReferenciaP" contenteditable>'+data[count].ReferenciaP+'</td>';

          html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id_perfil+'" data-column_name="cuenta_asociada" contenteditable><select id="Select" class="seleccionarusuario" name="select"></select></td>';

          html += '<td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="'+data[count].id_perfil+'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">Eliminar</button></td></tr>';
        }
        $('tbody').html(html);
      }
    });
  }

  load_data();
```

**Function for save it**

```
$(document).on('blur', '.table_data', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('row_id');
    var table_column = $(this).data('column_name');
    var value = $(this).text();       


    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>planificacion/update_mecanizado",
      method:"POST",
      data:{id:id, table_column:table_column, value:value},
      success:function(data)
      {
        load_data();
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: You can add the selected value to data in AJAX call.

Comment: @Triby can you be more specific please?

Comment: First get the value: **var select = $('Select').val();** then add it to the data: **data:{id:id, table_column:table_column, value:value, select:select},**

Comment: @Triby i got it.But i need the var select only when i change the select option, if i change for excample "Referencia" column the var value its ok but when i change the select i dont need the var value.